# Как сделать вывод текста по символу с SetInterval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Делаю директиву на angular. Надо переданный в директиву текст вывести посимвольно с интервалом в секунду. Я беру переданную строку, разбиваю её split по символам, и вот что дальше?

```
function ShowTextController() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.dataW ;
      var i;           
     vm.text = vm.data.split('');    

     function show(symbol) {
       vm.dataW = symbol;            
     } 

     for (i = 0; i < vm.text.length; i++)
        {
      setInterval( show , 1000,vm.text[i]); 
        }     
    }
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/23lISTggPlvXzWI4zBtq?p=preview)

Comment: setInterval ставит на постоянное выполнение. лучше использовать setTimeout и либо кучу таймаутов с _разным_ временем. Но лучше один таймаут который выведет очередной символ и запланирует вызов себя через еще секунду т.е. выполнит сам setTimeot

Comment: вы хотите чтобы в итоге был выведен весь текст? или последняя буква?

Comment: Весть текст....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы маньяк :). Одного Interval достаточно.

```
function ShowTextController($scope, $attrs) {
  var vm = this;

  var text_arr = $attrs['data'].split('');
  vm.data = '';

  var i = 0;
  var _timer = null;

  function _showLetter() {
    if (i >= text_arr.length) {
      clearInterval(_timer);
      return;
    }

    vm.data += text_arr[i++];
    $scope.$digest();
  }

  _timer = setInterval(_showLetter, 200);

}
```

В работе (там чуть больше изменений):

http://plnkr.co/edit/Eu91q4muyiuikOAgJvA0?p=preview

Comment: Хм, спасибо. А зачем $digest там?

Comment: $digest() запускает валидацию scope. Ангулар не знает когда изменения произошли. Он отслеживает действия пользователя (click,  mousemove, etc..) но вот таймер он отследить не может. Поэтому мы руками сообщаем ему, что "наш scope изменился, пересчитай пожалуйста"

Comment: Да, обновлять придется (хотел без вотчеров обойтись). Спасибо вам.

Comment: Что бы не использовать `$scope.$digest();` лучше использовать встроенный в ангуляр сервис `$interval`. Логика работы точно такая же, как и `setInterval`.